# MySQL sorting, ignoring first two symbols in the start

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I currently have the following code

```
SELECT Name
FROM Menu
WHERE Name LIKE 'S%'
ORDER BY LEFT(Name, 2)
```

Name must begin with S and I must to sort the result by alphabet, ignoring first two symbols in the start, I have no idea how to sort this

Comment: `LEFT` returns the first 2 characters of a string, not removes them. Also, SQL Server <> MySQL. Considering the title, I have removed the tag [tag:sql-server].

Comment: Does `SELECT Name, LEFT(Name, 2)` return what you expected?

Comment: @jarlh No, it doesnt return

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
order by substr(name, 3)
```

This picks up everything from the third character onward.